# Approximate pool time if $2$ peoples make random shots

Tags: probability

Me and my friend just thinking about that from several days. If $2$ people play blackball pool without doing fault and play one after the other, with $10$ seconds of thinking before each shot, with total random angles (even for the break, the player just have to touch the white ball, but with a random angle and a random force, like small, medium or strong) how much time it can take to put all the balls? I said something between $5$ and $10$ years, he says $1$ day. Is it possible to compute that with probability or something like that?

Edit: Just in $2D$, so the angle can be only on the centre of the white ball, from $0$ to $360$. If the white ball is plot we just put it to the middle of the line in front of the triangle.

Comment: What is that probability that a particular stroke pots $1$ ball when there are $n$ balls on the table? $2$ or more balls?

Comment: To be honest I don’t have the mathematical notions to answer you comment :/